# Whats the difference between Depot and Warehouse?

Tags: original-war

In the game Original War you can upgrade your Depot to Warehouse, but I don't really see whats the advantage of the Warehouse over the Depot.

[image: Depot / Warehouse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Иво Недев wrote](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/270257/whats-the-difference-between-depot-and-warehouse/270265#270265), the sphere of influence in which you can construct / link buildings grows:[image]

Apart from this, the building gets an armor bonus that depends on its level.

Answer (score 1):

Having a read [here](https://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/436368-original-war/faqs/15798), it seams that

> An upgraded depot gets a wider sphere of influence.

Also in the same walk trough, it looks like its part of Mission 13 as well.

Comment: What do you meant part of mission 13? You will see warehouse literally in each mission except where you don't need the upgrade depot and don't have access to it in any case.

Comment: According to the walk-trough you need to upgrade the depot as part of the mission.

Comment: The upgraded depot let you widen your influence radius and let you setup a bigger base than a typical depot would be able to. That FAQ is a guide to how to do mission and the upgrade depot are not required in most of them except to make more optimization approach to base layout. Not to mention mission 13 (all variations) objectives do not require you to make a warehouse at all. Most of them require you to build a rocket or accomplish something else without warehouse.